# Appropriate Index for a JOIN clause

Tags: sql

Lets say that I have the following tables with the given attributes:

TableA: A_ID, B_NUM,C,D
TableB: B_ID, E, F

Having the following query:

```
SELECT TableA.*,TableB.E,TableB.F FROM TableA
INNER JOIN TableB ON TableA.B_NUM=TableB.B_ID
```

What index would benefit this query?

I am having a hard time compreending this subject, in terms of what index should I create where.

Thanks!

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Answer (score 1):

This query:

```
SELECT a.*, b.E, b.F
FROM TableA a INNER JOIN
     TableB b
     ON a.B_NUM = b.B_ID;
```

is returning all data that matches between the two tables.

The general advise for indexing a query that has no `WHERE` or `GROUP BY` is to add indexes on the columns used for the joins.  I would go a little further.

My first guess of the best index would be on `TableB(b_id, e, f)`.  This is a covering index for `TableB`.  That means that the SQL engine can use the index to fetch `e` and `f`.  It does not need to go to the data pages.  The index is bigger, but the data pages are not needed.  (This is true in most databases; sometimes row-locking considerations make things a bit more complicated.)

On the other hand, if `TableA` is really big and `TableB` much smaller so most rows in `TableA` have no match in `TableB`, then an index on `TableA(B_NUM)` would be the better index.

You can include both indexes and let the optimizer decide which to use (it is possible the optimizer would decide to use both, but I think that is unlikely).